# Get results from table as diverse as possible

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to retrieve rows from a table based on some search criteria. The results I get have to meet those criteria and should additionally deliver a sample of the data that is as diverse as possible. A query with the same search criteria should always return the same sample though. So using `RAND()` in the query is no solution. The results are used to be displayed on a PHP driven website.

**Example**

I've got a table with accommodations, e.g. hotels, Bed&Breakfast or campgrounds. For every accommodation, there are additional informations like rating, budget, city and region. So the table basically looks like this:

```
| id | name   | type    | rating | budget | city         | region  |
|  1 | A Name | Hotel   |      2 |      2 | New York     | East    |
|  2 | B Name | B&B     |      3 |      2 | New York     | East    |
|  3 | C Name | Hotel   |      4 |      3 | New York     | East    |
|  4 | A Name | Hotel   |      3 |      4 | Chicago      | Central |
|  5 | D Name | B&B     |      4 |      3 | Chicago      | Central |
|  6 | E Name | Hotel   |      2 |      2 | Omaha        | Central |
|  7 | F Name | Hotel   |      5 |      4 | Omaha        | Central |
|  8 | G Name | Camping |      2 |      4 | Yosemite     | West    |
```

I now need a query that gets ten accommodations from e.g. `region='Central'` which contains as many cities as possible, as many accommodation types as possible, cheap accommodations as well as expensive ones and so on. I don't need a mathematically perfect solution, just something consistent.

**Idea 1**

I could query the table multiple times, with several different where clauses and mix the results. But querying multiple times is a big drawback for a web application.

**Idea 2**

I could introduce an additional column `random` that is filled by a random value while inserting the data and then do an `order by random`. The drawback of this solution is that random is a bad heuristic for what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I think you may do 2 query. One with `GROUP BY city` and one without. The first query should guarantee to have as much different cities as possible while the second is the fallback if there is not enough output.

Comment: You can use multiple GROUP BY statements for the data. Arrange them left to right according to the priority. As in `GROUP BY city, budget, rating`.